# Database Cardinality Relation Olympiad Questions?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, relational-database, cardinality

I ran into a question on local Olympiad for Database Contest. It asks which of the following is true about the cardinality of an expression involving relations.

[image]

The last option is: if A be a key of relation R and B be a foreign key of relation S we have:

[image]

Can any expert verify which is correct?

Comment: The fact that you needed to edit the question to add the fourth option is a mild nuisance.  Dropping your suggested answer (which was originally option 3, the union) after getting an answer is … mildly dubious.  It would have been best if you had explained why you thought each of the options was correct or incorrect; we'd be able to help you understand where you are having problems.

Comment: sorry thanks okey. you are so expert and kind @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original version of the question listed the first three options and was trying to verify that the third was correct.

1. The upper bound on Card(R - S) is Card(R), not Card(S).  If S is empty, then Card(R - S) is the same as Card(R).  Increasing the number of elements in S does not add to the result.
2. The upper bound on Card(R × S) is Card(R) multiplied by Card(S) — assuming the × means product.  If it doesn't, identify what it does mean.
3. The upper bound on Card(R ∪ S) is Card(R) plus Card(S) because the result could contain every element of R and every element of S if there is no element in common between R and S.

So, none of the first three suggested statements seems correct to me — I'd have to choose the ***none of the above*** option.

---

Then the question was changed to add the fourth statement.

4. Given that R(A) is a primary key of R and S(B) is a foreign key in S referencing R(A), then Card(R ⋈<sub>A=B</sub> S) is the join of R and S on the foreign key, so there can be at most the number of rows in S in the result (it would be less if the foreign key constraint is violated, so there's a row in S with no match in R).

So, under the revised question, the answer is Option 4, the join.

Comment: I edit my question, one option is forgotten !:) sorry